# how to make a phase shift on PWMs

Tags: c, cortex-m3, stm32f10x

I want to generate 2 PWM on PC6 & PC7 on an STM32f10x , it work fine but , the problem that I have is that I want to make them phase shifted to each other , say 45° and I really don't how to do that, since the PWM started  at the same time. any idea how tihis could be made.

thanks for any hint

Comment: A complex waveform like PWM has many frequencies and therefore many phase relationships. 45 degrees is meaningless - I think you want a fixed time displacement.

Comment: @Andyaka  NO  the fequency  it'S about to signals with the same frequency that are phase shifted to eached other

Comment: that makes absolutely no sense

Comment: why not how do you want to control a 3 or 4 phase motor ?

Comment: I am not familiar with that STM32, but PWM engines that have that possibility are generally advertised as such. Instead of one match register per channel they have two (plus one to reset the counter).

Comment: @Andyaka: Your initial comment makes no sense. Even a complex waveform has a fundamental frequency, and it's perfectly reasonable to talk about delaying it by 45 degrees, or 1/8 of its period.

Comment: @DaveTweed then what will happen to all the complexities of the PWM waveform. My initial comment makes total sense - you can't expect the fundamental to be phase shifted by 45 degrees and all the higher harmonics to shift in-line to keep the original shape of the pwm signal. That would be madness.

Comment: @Andyaka: Why would that be madness? That's the way it's done all the time! Remember, we're talking about driving a motor here, so the "phase angle" we're talking about relates to the rotation of the motor shaft.

Comment: @DaveTweed I know that - after the 2nd comment by the OP that became clear. Putting that as a comment does not make the question very clear.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do that inside your code, try taking a look at [this solution](https://my.st.com/public/STe2ecommunities/mcu/Lists/STM32Discovery/Flat.aspx?RootFolder=%2Fpublic%2FSTe2ecommunities%2Fmcu%2FLists%2FSTM32Discovery%2F%5BHELP%5D%20STM32F4%20generate%20PWM%203%20channel%20shift%20phase%20120%20degree!&FolderCTID=0x01200200770978C69A1141439FE559EB459D75800084C20D8867EAD444A5987D47BE638E0F&currentviews=1898). Alternatively, you could use a special IC for this task. [Here is the example](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slua122/slua122.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

So don't start the Timers at the same time. For a given angle, both Timers run at the same frequency. for example 1000  Hz has a period of 1000 uSec. 45 degrees is 1/8 of the period or 1000 uSec/8 = 125 uSec.

If you start the Timers 125 uSec apart -- with a frequency of 1000 Hz, you have a 45 degree phase difference. Now you can control duty-cycle of each PWM and the result is PSPWM.

If the 1st (or a separate) Timer has an extra PWM channel, you could assign its output-compare to have a value of 1/8 of the N-Divider that determines the 1000 Hz frequency. An interrupt at that 1/8 point could delay-start the second Timer with decent precision.

FWIW